# java.io.IOException: Error while finalizing cipher while decrypting sub-strings

Tags: encryption, android-keystore

I am running into an issue that I am not sure the proper fix. I used this thread as reference:

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64 when decrypting string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987424/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-bad-base-64-when-decrypting-string)

Basically I split a string into chunks and encrypt each chunk. But when it is time to decrypt the same way it never works. It always gives me this annoying exception:

"java.io.IOException: Error while finalizing cipher"

basically I split the string as below:

```
static public class RSAString {
    private ArrayList<String> mChunkList = new ArrayList<String>();
    RSAString() {
        mChunkList.clear();
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getChunkList() {
        return mChunkList;
    }
    RSAString(String stringSrc) {
        if (stringSrc.length() < CHUNK_SIZE) {
            mChunkList.add(stringSrc);
        } else {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < stringSrc.length() / CHUNK_SIZE; i++) {
                String subString = stringSrc.substring(j, j + CHUNK_SIZE);
                mChunkList.add(subString);
                j += CHUNK_SIZE;
            }
            int leftOver = stringSrc.length() % CHUNK_SIZE;
            if (leftOver > 0) {
                String subString = stringSrc.substring(j, j + leftOver);
                mChunkList.add(subString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I decrypt with this code:

```
// This **DOES NOT** work
final String AndroidOpenSSLString = "AndroidOpenSSL";
final String AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaroundString = "AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround";
mProvider = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M ? AndroidOpenSSLString : AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaroundString;
Cipher outCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", mProvider);
outCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mPrivateKey);
for (String chunkEncrypted : rsaEcryptedText.getChunkList()) {
    byte[] cipherText = chunkEncrypted.getBytes("UTF-8");
    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP)), outCipher);
    ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
    int nextByte;
    while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        values.add((byte) nextByte);
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = values.get(i);
    }
    decryptedString += new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");
    cipherInputStream.close();
    cipherInputStream.reset();
}
```

The only work around I found was to re-initialize the cypher every new sub-string. Like the hack below:

```
for (String chunkEncrypted : rsaEcryptedText.getChunkList()) {
    // This works, but I am re-initializing the out cypher every time!
    // super slow!!! WHY DO I HAVE TO DO THIS?
    Cipher outCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", mProvider);
    outCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mPrivateKey);
    byte[] cipherText = chunkEncrypted.getBytes("UTF-8");
    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP)), outCipher);
    ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
    int nextByte;
    while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        values.add((byte) nextByte);
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = values.get(i);
    }
    decryptedString += new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");
    cipherInputStream.close();
    cipherInputStream.reset();
}
```

The problem with my fix is that it makes the decryption much slower. Also, even with my sub-strings at small sizes (sub-string int CHUNK_SIZE = 64) I keep getting the same exception.

Anyway, I wonder if anyone can point me out the correct way to decrypt a long string with RSA encryption.

and here is the encryption code--not sure if it matters in this case--but it always works:

```
Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", mProvider);
inCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mPublicKey);
RSAString rsaStringPlainText = new RSAString(plainText);
for (String chunkPlain : rsaStringPlainText.getChunkList()) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
            outputStream, inCipher);
    cipherOutputStream.write(chunkPlain.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    cipherOutputStream.flush();
    cipherOutputStream.close();
    byte[] ecryptedText = Base64.encode(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    encryptedStringOut.mChunkList.add(new String(ecryptedText));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RSA** is not suited for bulk encryption as it's quite slow (more than a factor 1000 when compared to **AES**). Instead use a symmetric encryption algorithm like **AES** if you can. If you need the two key's of **RSA**, use [**Hybrid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) encryption where you encrypt the data with a random symmetric key, and then encrypt that key with the **RSA** key.

Another benefit of symmetric encryption is that libraries automatically supports bulk encryption, where you don't need to handle chopping your data up into small blocks before encryption.